# How to follow user on twitter using PHP libraries (EpiTwitter maybe?)

Tags: php, twitter

I want to follow some user on twitter. Can't seem find the function to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Zend_Service_Twitter from the Zend Framework. It is pretty easy to use, and as any ZF component, can be used without the need for the entire framework to be installed. See the manual for more information: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.service.twitter.html

Answer (score 1):

Here is the resource in the twitter api [POST friendships/create](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/post/friendships/create)

If you're using EpiTwitter library, after you authorize and have the access token you just need to call the EpiTwitter::post function

```
$resp = $twitterObj->post('/friendships/create.json', array('user_id' => $user_id_you_want_to_follow));
```

Regards